# Force AWS EMR to unzip files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, metadata

I have a bucket in AWS's S3 service that contains gzipped CSV files, however when they were stored they all were saved with the metadata Content-Type of text/csv.

Now I am using AWS EMR, which will not recognize them as a zipped file and unzip them. I've looked through configuration option for EMR but don't see anything that would work... I have almost a million files, so renaming their metadata value would require a Boto script that cycled through all the files and renamed the metadata value.

Am I missing something easy? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type` isn't the problem... that's correct if the files are csv, but if you stored them gzipped, then you needed to *also* have set `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the header metadata.  Doing that "should" trigger the useragent that's fetching them to gunzip them on the fly when they are downloaded... so had you done that, it should have "just worked."

(I store gzipped log files this way, with `Content-Type: text/plain` and `Content-Encoding: gzip` and when you download them with a web browser, the file you get is no longer gzipped because the browser untwizzles the compression on the fly due to the Content-Encoding header.)

But, since you've already uploaded the files, I did find this in the google machine, which might help:

> **GZipped input.** A lot of my input data had already been gzipped, but luckily if you pass `-jobconf stream.recordreader.compression=gzip` in the extra arguments section Hadoop will decompress them on the fly before passing the data to your mapper.

http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2010/01/elastic-mapreduce-tips.html